# Angular11 ignored directive

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I tried to create a reactive form compatible component for numbers. My component contains a directive to format numeric data.

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <div class="field">
        <span class="field-label" [innerHtml]="label"></span>
        <div class="input-group">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            <input class="k-textbox" currencyTransform [formControlName]="fieldName" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`currencyTransorm` is my directive and this is how it's declared:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[currencyTransform]"
})
export class CurrencyTransformDirective implements OnDestroy {
    ...
}
```

Now I have some different modules. One module to export all components (in this case only `NumeriFieldComponent`):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        NumericFieldComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        NumericFieldComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

One module for my test page:

```
let routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: TestComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TestRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestComponent
    ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

The last module is `app.module.ts` where I declare `CurrencyTransformDirective`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CurrencyTransformDirective
    ],
    imports: [
        // SOME IMPORTS
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // SOME PROVIDERS
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It's seems all ok but my directive is ignored. I tried with `console.log` in the constructor but nothing is written to the browser console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has you imported the ComponentsModule in the module where you has your component with the reactiveForms?

Comment: Is it possible your directive is not imported at all, and you don't have error ? I don't remember if angular throw error on unknown custom directives ( when you call them without parameter ).
 Can you try to add your directive in the component module, just to try

Comment: @Eliseo reactive forms works fine. The only issue is on directive

Comment: @KevinALBRECHT I don't have any error. I already tried to add directive in `ComponentsModule` without success.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the names of the directive and the module. If you has a Module where you declare the directive (declare and export) an another module where you declare your component, you need import the module of the directive in the last one. If the directive is in the same module that the component you don't need do it anything

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a new module for directive. I imported the new module on `ComponentsModule` and now it works fine.